# получение cookies jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

при отправке запроса jsoup на сайт, хочу получить cookies, но проблема в том, что один из cookies имеет странное значение и, соответственно, дальнейшая работа с данными куками неудачна, хотя через инспектор в браузере в Network показывает что все три куки имеют точное значение, запросы пытаюсь отправлять на сайт https://eios.kesip.ru/login/index.php, в чём может быть проблема?

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://eios.kesip.ru/login/index.php")
                    .userAgent(user_agent)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            Map<String, String> coky = response.cookies();

            System.out.println(coky);
```

данный вывод отдаст значение следующего типа:

```
{MoodleSession=83f2771f3f18096492d86cf6b75760e0, MoodleSessionTest=PHCP58EDqH, MOODLEID1_=deleted}
```

И вот параметр MOODLEID1_ имеет значение deleted, хотя Network в браузере показывает значение отличное от deleted, что с этим можно сделать или где я допускаю ошибку? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Может все дело в `user_agent` или еще каком заголовке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант могу предложить воспользоваться не `Jsoup` а `OkHttp`. Для начала я проверил что у вас сайт и правда что-то выдает нужно через Postman:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше добавляем в `build.gradle` зависимость:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2'
```

и посылаем запрос:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            val result = isInternetAvailable()
            println(result!!.headers.get(name = "Set-Cookie"))
        }
    }


    private suspend fun someFunction(): Response? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            try {
                val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .build()
                val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://eios.kesip.ru/login/index.php")
                    .method("GET", null)
                    .build()
                return@withContext client.newCall(request).execute()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("within exception$e")
                return@withContext null
            }
        }
    }
```

что на выходе выдает нам:

```
MOODLEID1_=%25B5%2589%25D6%25CC%25D6%25CD;
```

но это пример на kotlin, а вот пример на Java:

```
new Thread(() -> {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://eios.kesip.ru/login/index.php")
                    .get()
                    .build();

            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                System.out.println(response.header("Set-Cookie"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
```

ответ выдается такой же.

### UPDATE

Чтобы отправить в запросе json, можно сделать так:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("KEY1", "VALUE1");
    jsonObject.put("KEY2", "VALUE2");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

val client = OkHttpClient()
val mediaType = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()
val body = jsonObject.toString().toRequestBody(mediaType)
val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://YOUR_URL/")
            .post(body)
            .build()

var response: Response? = null
try {
    response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    val resStr = response.body!!.string()
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

что тоже нужно выполнять в отдельном треде ввиду ассинхронности. В примере то что вам нужно находится в `jsonObject` только поля и значения подставляйте свои.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140846/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew--cookies-jsoup).